# Manual way to draw accuracy/loss graphs

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolution, accuracy, model-evaluations

During the training process of the convolutional neural network, the network outputs the training/validation accuracy/loss after each epoch as shown below:

```
Epoch 1/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2174s 3s/step - loss: 0.6473 - acc: 0.6257 - val_loss: 0.5394 - val_acc: 0.8258
Epoch 2/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2145s 3s/step - loss: 0.5364 - acc: 0.7692 - val_loss: 0.4283 - val_acc: 0.8675
Epoch 3/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2124s 3s/step - loss: 0.4341 - acc: 0.8423 - val_loss: 0.3381 - val_acc: 0.9024
Epoch 4/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2126s 3s/step - loss: 0.3467 - acc: 0.8880 - val_loss: 0.2643 - val_acc: 0.9267
Epoch 5/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2123s 3s/step - loss: 0.2769 - acc: 0.9202 - val_loss: 0.2077 - val_acc: 0.9455
Epoch 6/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2118s 3s/step - loss: 0.2207 - acc: 0.9431 - val_loss: 0.1654 - val_acc: 0.9575
Epoch 7/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2125s 3s/step - loss: 0.1789 - acc: 0.9562 - val_loss: 0.1348 - val_acc: 0.9663
Epoch 8/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2120s 3s/step - loss: 0.1472 - acc: 0.9655 - val_loss: 0.1117 - val_acc: 0.9719
Epoch 9/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2119s 3s/step - loss: 0.1220 - acc: 0.9728 - val_loss: 0.0956 - val_acc: 0.9746
Epoch 10/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2119s 3s/step - loss: 0.1037 - acc: 0.9774 - val_loss: 0.0828 - val_acc: 0.9781
Epoch 11/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2110s 3s/step - loss: 0.0899 - acc: 0.9806 - val_loss: 0.0747 - val_acc: 0.9793
Epoch 12/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2123s 3s/step - loss: 0.0785 - acc: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.0651 - val_acc: 0.9825
Epoch 13/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2130s 3s/step - loss: 0.0689 - acc: 0.9860 - val_loss: 0.0557 - val_acc: 0.9857
Epoch 14/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2124s 3s/step - loss: 0.0618 - acc: 0.9874 - val_loss: 0.0509 - val_acc: 0.9869
Epoch 15/100
691/691 [==============================] - 2122s 3s/step - loss: 0.0555 - acc: 0.9891 - val_loss: 0.0467 - val_acc: 0.9876
Epoch 16/100
152/691 [=====>........................] - ETA: 22:10 - loss: 0.0515 - acc: 0.9892
```

My plan was to get the history variable and plot the accuracy/loss as follows:

```
history=model.fit_generator( .... )
plt.plot(history.history["acc"]) ...
```

But my training just stopped due to some hardware issues. Therefore, the graphs were not plotted. But I have the log of 15 epochs as mentioned above. Can I plot the accuracy/loss graph from the above log?

Comment: You should be able to, but if I understand correctly you do not have the accuracy and loss saved to a variable so you'd have to manually take them from the log you've shown.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I assumed the same way as you described! I will share the script to read the log and plot the curves. It might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers your issue in the Keras documentation
https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback

````
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

history = LossHistory()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=0, callbacks=[history])

print(history.losses)
# outputs
'''
[0.66047596406559383, 0.3547245744908703, ..., 0.25953155204159617, 0.25901699725311789]
```
````

Comment: You are right but as the training disconnected, I lost all the variables. Hence, I think I need to write a python script to manually collect losses and accuracies from the above log and plot the graph as suggested by Oxbowerce

Comment: Let us know how that works. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I came to a custom parser of logs. Simpler to run than to setup saving of statistics for TensorBoard sometimes. Then also inserted printing of losses with higher precision and also parsed it... Fast and quite convenient to run in parallel Jupyter notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

def getLogAsTable(srcFilePath):
    table = []
    fieldNames = ['epochNum', 'trainLoss', 'trainAcc', 'valLoss', 'valAcc']
    with open(srcFilePath, 'r') as file:
        preciseCorrection = False
        epochNum = 0
        for line in file:
            # Parsing "- 9s - loss: 9.9986e-04 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 9.9930e-04 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00"
            match = re.match(r'\s*- .+?s - loss\: (\d.*?) - acc\: (\d.*?)'
                             ' - val_loss: (\d.*?) - val_acc\: (\d.*)', line)
            if match:
                epochNum += 1
                row = [epochNum] + [float(valStr) for valStr in match.groups()]
                if len(row) != len(fieldNames):
                    raise Exception('Value count mismatch (%s)' % line)
                table.append(row)

    return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=fieldNames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logTable = getLogAsTable('log.txt')
    xs = logTable['epochNum']
    ys = logTable['trainLoss']
    plt.plot(xs, ys)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with your actual accuracy and loss values from training logs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
train_accuracy = [0.6257, 0.7692, 0.8423, 0.8880, 0.9202, 0.9431, 0.9562, 0.9655, 0.9728, 0.9774,
                  0.9806, 0.9835, 0.9860, 0.9874, 0.9891]

val_accuracy = [0.8258, 0.8675, 0.9024, 0.9267, 0.9455, 0.9575, 0.9663, 0.9719, 0.9746, 0.9781,
                0.9793, 0.9825, 0.9857, 0.9869, 0.9876]

train_loss = [0.6473, 0.5364, 0.4341, 0.3467, 0.2769, 0.2207, 0.1789, 0.1472, 0.1220, 0.1037,
              0.0899, 0.0785, 0.0689, 0.0618, 0.0555]

val_loss = [0.5394, 0.4283, 0.3381, 0.2643, 0.2077, 0.1654, 0.1348, 0.1117, 0.0956, 0.0828,
            0.0747, 0.0651, 0.0557, 0.0509, 0.0467]

epochs = range(1, 16)  # Assuming 15 epochs


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs, train_accuracy, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_accuracy, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs, train_loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Using this you should be able to plot the accuracy/loss graph using only your epochs.